# How do I detect if an image is a png with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, png

I need some way to mark PNGs with jQuery. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Rephrase this to be in proper question/answer form.

Comment: Never mind. I went and did this for you. Read the latest stackoverflow blog post to see why you should always follow the format of the site.

Answer (score 3):

In order to select image elements with a png extension in jQuery, you can use [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For your question, you want to match any `img` element with a `src` attribute that ends with (`$=`) `.png`, so your solution would be `$("img[src$='.png']")`. If you want to mark those items with a specific class (say, `png`), you would do: `$("img[src$='.png']").addClass('png');`

You can use the same style to select elements with any attribute you desire. For instance, to find all anchors with a hash value for the `href` attribute, you can use: `$("a[href^='#']")`

jQuery has a big list of different types of selectors, which you can read about here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/